# Is it possible to change the highlight or background color of the "search results" from the help menu in RStudio?

Tags: themes, rstudio

I'm able to change the colour of selected text in the RStudio script window. For this I changed the

```
.ace_marker-layer .ace_selection {
  background: #9D0000; 
}
```

in the `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/resources/themes/chaos.rstheme`

But whenever I do a search in the 'Help' panel, the highlighted background is a faint grey and would like to change it. Where could I find the value that needs to be changed for this?

The reason is that it is super hard to see the highlighted background in the help and a colour change would make it much easier to search in the help menu!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing your **.rstheme** file,
Append the following lines to the end of the file:

```
.rstudio-themes-dark.editor_dark.ace_editor_theme ::selection {
    background: rgba(179, 101, 57, 0.75) !important;
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

If that does not work,

1. duplicate your **.rstheme** file, and rename the first row with a unique identifier, like so:

   /* rs-theme-name: Cobalt (SELECTHELP) */
2. Append the previous lines to the end of the file.
3. In RStudio, go to **Tools** > **Global Options** > **Appearance**
4. Click **"Add..."**
5. Select the previously edited file

Of course, you can change the color to match your preferred theme... I use **Cobalt**, as any reasonable person would do :)

Before & After image:
[image: Before (Left), After (Right)]